# linechart achartengine showcustomtextgridYon right side while all other labels on left

Tags: android, achartengine

[image: images of line chart with custom textfields added on right side]Is there a way where i can add all labels of line chart (using achartengine) on left side but keep the custom text grids added on y axes to right side ?
Because when i setCustomTextGridY it sets the custom texts to left side where the labels are present.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106645/achartengine-on-android-multiple-y-axis

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786435/achartengine-graph-using-two-y-axis